# Cambiar modelo dependiendo de un Jason Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Tengo el siguiente json que es recibido en un controller

```
{
  "aplicacion": "miaplicacion",
  "operation": "mioperacion",
  "mensaje":{
              "oficio": 5,
  },
  "lugar": "mifecha",
}
```

como puedo hacer para cambiar el modelo al que hace referencia dependiendo del mensaje, es decir, si es oficio se recibe con un modelo "mioficiomodel", si el mensaje cambia, por ejemplo:

```
{
  "aplicacion": "miaplicacion",
  "operation": "mioperacion",
  "mensaje":{
              "demanda": si,
  },
  "lugar": "mifecha",

}
```

debería cambiar el modelo al que hace referencia (midemandamodel), las propiedades como `aplicacion`, `operation` y `lugar` se mantienen en el json, solo cambia el mensaje, he creado un método

```
[HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> getmensaje([FromBody] mioficiomodel json)
```

pero este solo funciona con mioficiomodel, necesito hacerlo dinámico para que reciba un objeto y este haga el bind con el modelo respectivo, algún tip?

Comment: Considera usar un viewmodel que tenga los dos tipos de mensajes luego verifica con un if cual tipo de mensaje es y a partir de eso creas un objeto del modelo correspondiente

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es posible hacer

Puedes recibir un modelo genérico y luego con algún método factory generar el modelo que necesitas.

Otra forma es que tengas 2 entradas al API, una para cada modelo y utilizar la que corresponda desde el front (supongo que es ASP NET CORE API y no un controller de MVC).

Algo que se me ocurre, pero que nunca probe, es que el parámetro este tipificado con una Interfaz y entonces utilices una librera AOP o algún Custom Filter para tomar lo que viene y generar el modelo que necesites (obviamente los diferentes modelos extienden de una misma interfaz).